# Does the Trichotomy Property apply?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Problem:

If a, b >= 0 and a^2 < b^2, then a < b.

I believe I may show this to be true by analyzing the cases where a or b are equal to zero, a = b and, a > b and subsequently using the hypothesis to invalidate many of these cases.

For instance,

i) let a = 0 and b = 0, 0^2 < 0^2 is false.

ii) let a > 0 and b = 0, a^2 < 0^2 is false.

iii) let a = 0 and b > 0, 0^2 < b^2 is true.

iv) let a = b, b^2 < b^2 is false.

v) let a > b, then a*a < b*b is false:

Let P be positive numbers.

With, (a - b) > 0, we may get (bb < ba) or (b*b < b*a).
This reduces to (b*a) - (b*b) in P => b*(a-b). Both terms positive. 
Next, (b*a < a*a). This reduces to (a*a - b*a) in P => a*(a-b). Both terms positive. 
We now have: (b^2 < a^2) which contradicts our hypothesis that a^2 < b^2. Hence, a > b is false.

From these cases, a = b is false and a > b is false,

so by applying the Trichotomy Property, a < b must be true.

The purpose of this question is a clarification that the solution manual indicates that the decomposition of a^2 < b^2 to a < b may be done using the reasoning in case (v) above. However, I find that using this reasoning causes me to assume (b - a) is in P which is what I am trying to prove! Hence, I believe a circular logic argument - or at least a flawed argument.

My reasoning as stated above relies upon the principles of the Trichotomy Property and I am curious and eager to understand if this reasoning is accurate. Alternatively, if I am inaccurate I would equally prefer to know.